# Error adding numeric to text

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to loop with numbers, but with text the Do While does not loop through.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
     Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + 1
     i = i + 1
Loop
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop like that and you don't have any error when it comes to *VBA syntax*. The only problem is that the expression:

> `Cells(i, 1).Value + 1`

will raise a *runtime error* when `Cells(i, 1).Value` is not convertible to a number. That's simple, you have a *type mismatch* when `Cells(i, 1).Value` is a string like "abcd", you can't convert that variant to a number in order to add `1` to it.

In this situation it is not the fault of the macro code, but of the data.

To deal with heterogeneous data you can possibly *check* if a value is numeric before manipulating it as a number, like this:

```
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1).value) then Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + 1
  ' ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you A.S.H   I decided to go away to see the error relating to text.  So I was able to see your approach, but I decided to remove and duplicate the ending part to help me achieve what I need.  Your code +  & " - " & Cells(2, 2).Value

Comment: Good spot! I hope you don't mind I also added that - felt it was worth keeping my answer up too (+1 to you though!)

Comment: @CallumDA yes I think that your other remarks are useful as well.

Answer (score 3):

@A.S.H has spotted the real error here, but a few other things to note:

1. When looping through a column/row like this, it's usually better to use a `For Each` loop.
2. Using `Cells` on it's own makes an implicit reference to the `ActiveWorksheet`. It's best to explicitly reference which cells you are referring to, e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells`

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100") 'range to loop through

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> vbNullString and IsNumeric(r.value) Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Value + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you CallumDA, I did try to your code as I normally would when starting Insert > Module.  But there is some errors I get on the:  Set.  I did look into whether it was a variable issues (by looking at other posts) and noticed you made changes. I can confirm it is also a great solution too. The code works great.